# ClickOnce Published WPF Application starts but fail to open a specific window

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I am trying ClickOnce publishing service. I simply publish my solution to a share folder in online only mode, run the web page and my application starts.

I cick a button that open a window fine, another one, fine too and then a third one and the window don't show up.

What I know:

It's not a missing DLL, there is no exception (exception logger) and it's working fine in Release/Debug

Do you have any hint/idea why this and how to hunt for the problem ?

Comment: If you are 100% positive that you have included all of your DLLs and all prerequisites are installed on the client PC, there is no way to diagnose this problem without some code.  What type of Window are you trying to open?  Is it a dialog that you've created or is it part of a thrid-party app?  These are important details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the file to your project and set the build action to "content" and "copy to output directory" to "copy always". Then, because it's an XML file, go into the Application Files dialog in the Publish tab and change the file from "Include(Data)" to "Include(Required)".

If you deploy it as data, it will put it in the DataDirectory instead of including it in the same folder as the main assemblies. Include(Data) is the default for XML files. (Annoying, isn't it?)

Comment: The problem is that the XML file is part of a Business.DLL project inside my solution. The Ui project is the publisher. So on the `Ui > Publish > Application files` there is no XML file at all. I only see my Business.DLL (Which is a reference in the Ui project). I would have to move the XML file to the Ui project  in order to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I use a file-based trace tool. I found out that there was a problem with an XML file. I found a [blog post on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/karstenj/archive/2006/02/21/536322.aspx) that talks about that. I appear that the build action and the publish action ain't the same.

So the problem of the window was that it needed that XML file but didn't find it. It threw an exception but the exception logger didn't catch it because it was on another thread. (I then learned to foward exception to the main thread).

Finally, it seems you can't publish a file when it's from a DLL. It must be embedded to the DLL or moved to the main UI project (the published project).